# Angular http method: 'POST' não está enviando o objeto do $scope

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Estou com um problema no method post do http do angular, já vi várias dicas mas nenhuma funciona. Segue o código:

```
$scope.cadastrar = function () {
   $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/MinhaConta/Cliente/PostAnuncio',
        data: $.param($scope.novo),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    })
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        if (data.Status) {
           $scope.hasMsg = true;
           $scope.hasError = false;
           $scope.hasSuccess = true;
           $scope.infoMsg = data.Mensagem;
        }
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.hasMsg = true;
       $scope.hasSuccess = false;
       $scope.hasError = true;
       $scope.infoMsg = data.ErrorMessage;
    });
};
```

coloquei o escopo para exibir as informações do meu objeto conforme vou inserindo:

[image: Testando no Browser o bind do modelo]

Inseri um breakpoint para ver se o objeto possui valor

[image: Breakpoint]

O response acaba me devolvendo um erro que é um retorno padrão caso o objeto seja nulo.
Alguém saberia me dizer o que eu estou fazendo errado?

{
  "tipoid": 0,
  "marcaid": 0,
  "modeloid": 0,
  "versaoid": 0,
  "anofabricacao": 0,
  "anomodelo": 0,
  "km": 0,
  "valor": 0.0,
  "cor": null,
  "combustivel": null,
  "placa": null,
  "vscustom": null,
  "troca": false
}

```
public class NovoVeiculo
{
    public int tipoid { get; set; }
    public int marcaid { get; set; }
    public int modeloid { get; set; }
    public int versaoid { get; set; }
    public short anofabricacao { get; set; }
    public short anomodelo { get; set; }
    public int km { get; set; }
    public decimal valor { get; set; }
    public string cor { get; set; }
    public string combustivel { get; set; }
    public string placa { get; set; }
    public string vscustom { get; set; }
    public bool troca { get; set; }
}
```

Agradeço desde já a ajuda.

Comment: tenta passar a variavel data de forma diferente . exemplo: $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/MinhaConta/Cliente/PostAnuncio',
        data: {novo: $scope.novo)},
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    })

Comment: Seria bom [edit] e mostrar o conteúdo de `$scope.novo`

Comment: então tentei passar de outras formas mas o resquest no console do browser me mostra novo{ [] }

Comment: Sem mais informações eu diria que o problema está na hierarquia de escopo - talvez a propriedade `novo` esteja sendo criada em um sub-escopo. Na inicialização do *controller* onde você declara `$scope.cadastrar`, insira '$scope.novo = null' para que a variável seja inicializada no escopo correto.

Comment: @MeiaEsquerda você está certo, como a declaração do $scope.novo estava lá no começo eu acabei me esquecendo que inicializei ele como array... deu certo agora. Valeu pela observação.

Comment: @AngélicaFlausino que bom que funcionou! Para ajudar futuros usuarios com o mesmo problema, responda com sua solucao e marque como aceita. E nao por isso, eh sempre um prazer ajudar. 